# AngularJS. ui-view included in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

I try to use ui-view included in ng-view, and it does not work. But when I use ui-view near ng-view, ui-view work and in ng-view.

Don't work:

```
<div ng-view id="body-div"></div>
```

Work:

```
<div ui-view id="body-div"></div>
<div ui-view id="body-div"></div>
```

Example. http://plnkr.co/edit/WHWw5DNHBRWjo1JIGouq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not mix ng-view & ui-view. Only use ui-view if you plan to use ui-router.

See ui-router FAQ : [Don't do that](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-problems-when-using-ng-view-alongside-ui-view)